# Which Lightroom import presets should I use to get output like that from Capture NX?

Tags: nikon, lightroom, raw

When I import NEF photos into Lightroom, they do not look as good as they appear when importing into Capture NX.  The colours look a little more muddy and there is a lack of contrast.

This means that I have do a little more work in Lightroom to make them look better.

Are there any presets, that I can use on import, which I can use to make the photos look more like how they appear in Capture NX?

Comment: Excellent question.  I have a d300, and have wondered the same thing.

Comment: Refreshed version of essentially the same question: http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34288/which-lightroom-4-3-import-presets-should-i-use-for-nikon-d3200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best probably would be to create your own presets: fiddle the settings in LR dev until you like the result, store the settings as preset and apply this preset on future imports.

Maybe you will want to add some camera profiles (I've created my own [profiles (germany) for the D40 and D90](http://www.radeldudel.de/blog/1002/KameraprofileNikonD40D80D90PentaxK10D.html) and stored them for usage in Lightroom).

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for or not, but [Adobe Labs](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/DNG_Profiles) has a set of camera profiles for use with Lightroom and the D90 is supported.  Here is a link to the [DNG Profiles FAQ](http://labs.adobe.com/wiki/index.php/DNG_Profiles:FAQ).  Hope that helps!