# Which Lightroom 4.3 import presets will best replicate Nikon's Vivid Picture control setting?

Tags: nikon, raw, reverse-engineering, lightroom-4, presets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which Lightroom import presets should I use to get output like that from Capture NX?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/which-lightroom-import-presets-should-i-use-to-get-output-like-that-from-capture)

This question is very similar to [this question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3809/which-lightroom-import-presets-should-i-use-for-nikon-d40-and-d90) asked 2 years ago. However, its 2 years old and the links provided don't seem to lead to what they were intended for.

Whenever I import my NEF files from my Nikon D3200 into Lightroom 4.3, they look a bit blander than they do in View NX. My search online tells me that Lightroom does not recognize the "Vivid" picture control settings. I also found out that Lightroom has a "Camera Calibration" pane which lets me pick "Camera Vivid". Although this improves the picture, it still does not look the same as View NX, the shadows seem too dark.

What is the best and easiest way to replicate the Vivid Nikon settings in Lightroom?

Comment: We get this question for nearly every model of camera and the answer is still the same: None. Lightroom does its own development and has its own look. The same goes for other software. If you want the Nikon look, you better use the Nikon software.

Comment: I am hoping for an answer better than "None". I'm 100% sure that what I'm asking is not completely impossible. I'm not looking for a 100% match in computed RGB value for each pixel. I have an idea of how one can go about doing it. I just asked a question here hoping to learn from someone else's experience.

Comment: I think the answer is going to be the same as last time.  Pick the closest preset Lightroom has, play with contrast and saturation until it looks close to your eye, then save that preset and use it.

Comment: Well, that's _why_ the original question didn't get good answers. Maybe if you post some examples of results you like from View NX and your attempts to replicated them in Lightroom, we can figure out you might do to get them closer.

Comment: @Danish: If you really want to get as close as possible to Nikons camera profiles, you could try creating your own for Lightroom: [Playing with Color Camera Profiles](http://x-equals.com/blog/playing-with-color-camera-profiles-part-2-of-3/). Load up a color checker card in both Nikons image editing software, as well as Adobes profile creator. Rearrange the windows so you can alt-tab back and forth without any shifting of the color checker card. Tweak as needed to optimize the results, save, load into Lightroom.

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate of a 2 year old question. My take away is that absolutely nothing has changes in light of this question in the last 2 years? Correct?